# Eclipse IDE last edit location history - multiple steps back?

Tags: eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm now in a process of transition from Netbeans to Eclipse (Indigo).

**`Ctr+Q`** seems to have the same function - going back to the last edit location. But in Netbeans I was able to press **`Ctr+Q`** repeatedly and go further back without the need of altering the file content (**undo** and **redo** hack).

Is there such functionality in Eclipse?

Some info:

I'm using the JavaScript Development Toolkit, PDT, and YAML editor.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that **Back** action (**`Alt+Left`**) is more or less the same. The difference is that it tracks any action, not only edits. Actions as "Go to declarations" are also included in the history of **`Alt+Left`**.

I think, in a way, it's more useful because I track back my real actions as in *"real browsing"* the code. Though I will switch the keyboard shortcuts for **Last Edit** and **Previous Action** so that I keep the **`Ctr+Q`** habit.

Comment: Do you mean "Backward History" (`Alt+Left`) by "Previous Action"? If so, [that's no alternative](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=72773).

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible in Eclipse. There is an old feature request for this functionality with Bugzilla id 72773 (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=72773).

Answer (score 1):

9 years later, check out [Eclipse 4.17 (2020_09)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.17/platform.php#multiple-last-edit-locations)

> ### Multiple Last Edit Locations

> **Previous Edit Location** navigation (formerly named **Last Edit Location**) is now expanded to remember multiple edit locations.
> The last 15 edit locations are now remembered.
>
> For convenience, similar edit locations in close proximity to each other are also merged so that each of the 15 remembered locations remains distinct.
>
> [image: new menu item: Previous Edit Location]
>
> #### How to use
>
> Two new keyboard shortcuts are introduced:
>
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT_ARROW</kbd> (or on Mac <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT_ARROW</kbd>) navigates to the most recent edit location, just as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> always has in prior releases.
>   However, now continuing to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>LEFT_ARROW</kbd> again begins a traversal through the history of prior edit locations, with each additional press of <kbd>LEFT_ARROW</kbd> moving a step further back in history.
>   Once traversal stops, future <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT_ARROW</kbd> actions are now temporarily anchored to this older historical location for easy exploration of that code region.
>
> The classic <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> mapping has been likewise enhanced with this new functionality, so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT_ARROW</kbd> are synonymous.
>
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT_ARROW</kbd> (or on Mac <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT_ARROW</kbd>) conversely moves the anchor forward through edit history, so after traversing backward with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT_ARROW</kbd>, you can go forward again by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and repeatedly pressing <kbd>RIGHT_ARROW</kbd>.
>   A new menu item has likewise been added for this forward navigation as well.
>
> New edit locations are always inserted at the end, so original historical ordering is always maintained.
> New edits also reset the last location "anchor" back to the most recent edit, so that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt<kbd>+</kbd>LEFT_ARROW</kbd> once again brings you to the most recent edit rather than a historical one.

Comment: in this way CTRL + Q has lost its function, and it is very frustrating in my opinion.
it would have been better if CTRL + Q had stayed as it was and the new history used different keys

Comment: @AndreaScarafoni I agree. I suppose you could make your custom keyboard mapping in order to rectify that.

Comment: it seem that is not possible to have the simple "Last edit location", just the "next" or "previous", that is very different behavior

Comment: @AndreaScarafoni i agree. going through more edit locations is good, but they should've kept ctrl+q to jump straight to the latest edit. i've changed the binding so ctrl+q goes forward instead. (if i ever decide to see older edit locations then i just gotta spam ctrl+q to get back to the latest edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the local history if you lost your undo redo functions.
to do that: 1/ right click anywhere on your code, 2/ Team, 3/ Show Local History, then choose the version you want according to edit time.